# How can a server from US connect to a tier 1 ISP?

Tags: routing, fiber, isp

According to this graph : [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qxo5w.jpg) is a full size version

[image]

The facebook AS32934 server in the US is direcly connected to DE-CIX in germany. How can that be possible ? Is there fibers over the ocean ?

Comment: I recommend learning what an [autonomous system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_system_(Internet)) is; it's not a "server", and Facebook is large enough to actively manage physical presence and peering.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there fibers over the ocean ?

They're more under the Ocean but absolutely, you can see a somewhat accurate map of them [here](https://www.submarinecablemap.com/). These undersea cables are how continents are interconnected and will usually have `Tb/s` worth of capacity. It's also important to note that AS32934 is not just a single Facebook Server but rather a whole Network full of Routers, Switches, Fibre & Servers.

Comment: It might be helpful to clarify that Facebook is, essentially, its own ISP, and it peers directly with other ISPs in the normal ways that ISPs do.

Comment: And Facebook probably doesn't have its own fibre. Facebook probably leases a certain wavelength from another company that does own a fibre. They might even lease a layer-2 or layer-3 VPN from a third company, which leases from a company that owns a fibre - I don't think that would show up in the AS connectivity graph?

Comment: @user253751, Facebook definitely own their own Fibre, in fact, they've been key building partners in a few undersea cables. See here: https://engineering.fb.com/connectivity/fiber-optic-cable/

Answer (score 2):

> The facebook AS32934 server in the US is direcly connected to DE-CIX in germany. How can that be possible ? Is there fibers over the ocean ?

Note that this graph only shows IP routing. When a router in DE-CIX wants to send a packet to AS32934, it knows there is a link from DE-CIX to AS32934, so if it sends the packet out via that link, it will arrive at AS32934. *It does not know what type of link it is*.

It is likely that Facebook leases some kind of point-to-point VPN (or a real PN!) between one of their US server farms and DE-CIX. *The VPN is not routed* - traffic that comes in one end goes out the other end. So BGP doesn't need to know about it. At least, that's one possibility.

---

You'll also notice that this graph shows ASes, not servers. Roughly speaking, it shows which *companies* are connected to which other *companies*. Facebook is connected to DE-CIX. It doesn't tell you what *part* of Facebook is connected to DE-CIX. Facebook can have US servers and EU servers and some kind of connection between them - it's all included inside the box that says "Facebook". You wouldn't expect to see Facebook's internal connections here.

Comment: Facebook definitely own and build their own Fibre to connect their backbone, in fact, they've been key building partners in a few undersea cables. See here: engineering.fb.com/connectivity/fiber-optic-cable